# How to download pdf to iPhone

Tags: pdf

Can anyone explain me how to download this pdf book from this link http://www.linuxcommand.org/tlcl.php ?

Answer (score 0):

You would need a adobe acrobat reader to read that pdf in iphone and you can download by clicking on this page and click on "here" given on the same page.